# Checking an array if it contains an object by a specific property, objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two arrays of custom objects.  Both have properties of NSString *name.  I want to check if

```
object.name in array1 == object.name in array2
```

How would I do that?  Do I have to form a predicate?  I know I can brute force it and just enumerate over the objects in array2 to check if it has the same name, but I didn't know if there was a better-performing or ideal way to do this task.  Thanks.

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean. You want to check if each object in array1 has the same name as the object in the same index in array2, or you want to check if any object in array1 has the same name as any object in array2, or some third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're thinking is fine.  To the extent you do know types, specify them to be clear with the compiler and people reading the code in the future.  Also, use isEqualToString: to compare strings.

```
for (Foo *foo in myFooCollection) {
    for (Bar *bar in myBarCollection) {
        if ([foo.name isEqualToString:bar.name]) {
            // match
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing you might consider is implementing compare: on both Foo and Bar objects.

```
// Foo.m
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(id)otherObject {
    if ([otherObject isKindOfClass:[Bar self]]) {
        Bar *itsABar = (Bar *)otherObject;
        return [self.name compare:itsABar.name];
    } 
    return [super compare:otherObject];
}
```

And likewise for Bar.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSMutableSet's `intersectSet:` method.

1. Pull out the array of property values you want to intersect, and convert your first array to a mutable set: `NSMutableSet *setA = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[arrayA valueForKey:@"name"]];`
2. Intersect it with the property values in array B. `[setA intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[arrayB valueForKey:@"name"]];`

If you wanted to combine it into one really long line, you'd do this:

```
NSSet *commonProperties = [[NSMutableSet setWithArray:[arrayA valueForKey:@"name"]] intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[arrayB valueForKey:@"name"]]];
```

Of course, this is only going to give you the name property, not the object itself. If you wanted the entire object, override `isEqual:` and do the name check in there. Then you can eliminate the `valueForKey:` part and just intersect the two sets.

The remaining values will be the common values. `NSSet` string comparison uses `isEqualToString:` behind the scenes for `NSString` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use predicate, internally it will take each object in array and compare. Array is a `collection` not like primitive data types and there is no way to compare in a single fly.