# How to check If array has same object value before adding new value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am getting data from Dictionary. It works well and stores data in NSMutableArray I want that before adding object into need to make sure that Array does not contain same object with Same Name and Type. Please see below.

Before inserting object we should check that it does not contain object with Type and Name if contains no need to insert.

```
NSArray *resultDic = [result1 objectForKey:@"results"];

for (int i = 0; i<[resultDic count]; i++) {
    id item = [resultDic objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    GetData  *theObject =[[GetData alloc] init];

    NSString*error = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"error"];
    if(![error isEqualToString:@"No Record Found."])
    {



        [theObject setVaccineID:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"ID"]];
        [theObject setVaccineName:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"Name"]];
        [theObject setVaccinationType:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"Type"]];
        [theObject setVaccineType:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"VType"]];
        [theObject setFarmName:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"FName"]];
        [theObject setDay:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"Day"]];
        [theObject setAddedDateTime:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"DateTime"]];



        [appDelegate.dataArray addObject:theObject];



    }
}
```

Comment: Answer similar to >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387582/checking-an-array-if-it-contains-an-object-by-a-specific-property-objective-c

Comment: You can check by using containsObject.Check below link it might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6299064/5184217

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose solution is to teach your `GetData` object how to compare itself to others.  If they can be compared, then it will be easy to determine if a match is in any collection (and you might want to compare them in other contexts, too).  Do this by implementing `isEqual:`.  That might look something like this:

```
// in GetData.m
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[GetData self]]) {
        // assuming that the object is fully characterized by it's ID
        return [self.vaccineId isEqual:((GetData *)object).vaccineId];
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

// have the hash value operate on the same characteristics as isEqual
- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return [self.vaccineId hash];
}
```

With that done, you can take advantage of NSArray's [`containsObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1407477-containsobject?language=objc).

```
// ...
if(![appDelegate.dataArray containsObject:theObject] && ![error isEqualToString:@"No Record Found."])
// ...
```